# bootstrap datepicker z-index still not change

Tags: bootstrap-datepicker

my bootstrap-datepicker need to have a z-index at 13.

I set it with the argument zIndexOffset like in the doc.

But the result keep the z-index at 10 like default.

```
                $('.date-picker').datepicker({autoclose:true, language: 'fr', format: 'dd-mm-yyyy', zIndexOffset:13}).next().on(ace.click_event, function(){
                $(this).prev().focus();
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

1. find `bbostrap-datimepicker.min.js` change `return c(this).css("z-index")!="auto"}
   return c(this).css("z-index")!="9999"}`
2. `datetimepicker.css .datetimepicker {z-index:9999}`